# Update when something changes in the website Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, service, updates

I have a question, I have two separate , with two differents controllers, like this:

```
<div ng-app='demoApp'>
    <div ng-controller='FirstCtrl'>    
        {{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'}}
    </div>
    <div ng-controller='SecCtrl'>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="update()" >Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to update the date in the first controller when I do click in the botton of the second controller.

This is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wa8nsh9j/9/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making use of Factories in AngularJS :

1. Create a factory object and put the date property inside the object.
2. Populate the factory object property inside 'SecCtrl'
3. Assign the factory object property to $scope.date of 'FirstCtrl'

```js
demoApp.factory('DataFactory', function(a) {
  return {
    dateVal : null
  }
}); 

demoApp.controller("FirstCtrl", function(DataFactory) {
  //$scope.date = DataFactory.dateVal; //->This wont work
  $scope.date = DataFactory;
});

demoApp.controller("SecCtrl", function(DataFactory) {
  $scope.update = function() {
    DataFactory.dateVal = new Date();
  }
});
```

HTML UPDATE:

```html
<div ng-controller='FirstCtrl'>    
    {{date.dateVal | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'}}
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried this code ? I think it will not work - you are creating new object in `update` and that breaks `$watch` under the hood. http://jsfiddle.net/wa8nsh9j/12/

Comment: Creating a new object will not create a problem. The problem occurs when we assign that new object to $scope.date in 'FirstCtrl'. Thanks for the input. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you do `$scope.date = new Date()` then you replace the reference to your date property thus the other controller does not track it anymore. You have to store the reference to your UpDate service in $scope.model property to overcome this problem.

```
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, UpDate){  
        $scope.model = UpDate;                
    })
    .controller('SecCtrl', function($scope, UpDate){
        $scope.model = UpDate;        

        $scope.update = function () {
            $scope.model.date = new Date();
        };
    })
    .service('UpDate', function(){
        this.date = new Date();     
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wa8nsh9j/11/